# Facebook Photo upload works, but i have to allow the photo in my album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So, the photo upload with the PHP SDK to Facebook works.
But when the user uploads it in one of the his own albums, he first have to go to Facebook and press `allow`, only then the photo will be displayed on Facebook.

Is there a way to make sure it goes in one step (upload photo), instead of 2 (1. upload photo, 2. allow photo)? 

I am using the following permissions:
-> `publish_stream`,
-> `photo_upload`.
And the `setFileUpload` is on `true`.

I hope you can help me, so there won't be angry users because they think the uploading doesn't work..

Comment: If you need to approve the photo it's almost certainly because you don't have the `user_photos` permission, or you're trying to upload yo an existing album whose privacy settings are more open than what you've selected as the maximum privacy setting for the app

Comment: I have the `user_photos` permission, but it doesn't make a difference.
Its the second option about the privacy settings of the app. I set it to `Public` and now it's working great!
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this was figured out in the comments, a photo uploaded via the API needing to be confirmed usually means one of two things:

- You don't have the `user_photos` permission
- You are uploading to an album with more open visibility than what the user has chosen for your app - e.g. if the user selected 'Friends' as the maximum visibility for the app, and you try to upload to an existing album which is visible publicly, the user needs to approve each photo because otherwise you'd be overriding their selected privacy for the app